# C# List<> GroupBy functionality

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list like the below.

```
var list = new List<Currency>()
{
    new Currency() { Id = 1, CurrencyCode = "USD", BuyRate = 1.105478m,  SellRate = 1.154878m },
    new Currency() { Id = 2, CurrencyCode = "USD", BuyRate = 1.115487m , SellRate = 1.167487m },
    new Currency() { Id = 3, CurrencyCode = "USD", BuyRate = 1.121454m , SellRate = 1.145748m },
    new Currency() { Id = 4, CurrencyCode = "EUR", BuyRate = 1.415474m , SellRate = 1.550454m },
    new Currency() { Id = 5, CurrencyCode = "EUR", BuyRate = 1.424857m , SellRate = 1.564578m },
    new Currency() { Id = 6, CurrencyCode = "AUD", BuyRate = 2.154857m , SellRate = 2.487876m },
};
```

I want to get only one record per currencyCode. I want to get the record with the highest id for the currencies that have multiple record. So result list should look like this:

```
3  USD          1.121454  1.145748
5  EUR          1.424857  1.564578
6  AUD          2.154857  2.487876
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code, what have you tried?

Comment: EF deals with tables, not lists. LINQ queries are translated to SQL, so LINQ over EF can't do things that can't be expressed as SQL. Some things are easier to write in SQL than LINQ too. Essentially, you're asking for the "last" row per currency.

Comment: Have a look at `MaxBy`: `var result = myCollection.GroupBy(item => item.CurrencyCode).MaxBy(group => group.BuyRate);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko +1 but `group` variable name is very unfortunate :) it's not group, we group by single item property :)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `MaxBy` supported by Entity-Framework?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko +1 but I think it's more `var result = myCollection.GroupBy(item => item.CurrencyCode).Select(g => g.MaxBy(item => item.Id));`

Comment: can we do it with orderbydescending ?

Comment: @Magnus: technically yes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.maxby?view=net-7.0 - but it should be tried, e.g. https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5766919052690-R-recommends-MaxBy-that-is-not-supported-by-Entity-Framework

Comment: Why do you have an entity-framework tag? It's nowhere in your code.

Comment: @GertArnold I think this question was edited, the original post was compliant with the EF tag

Comment: @vc74 It should be clear whether the query is on an `IQueryable` and also EF's version is always important. The question never had that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a simple query:

```
IEnumerable<Currency> query =
    from c in list
    group c by c.CurrencyCode into gcs
    from gc in gcs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(1)
    select gc;
```

That gives me:

[image: query]

Or this, if you prefer method syntax:

```
IEnumerable<Currency> query =
    list
        .GroupBy(c => c.CurrencyCode)
        .SelectMany(gcs =>
            gcs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var result = list
        .GroupBy(x => x.CurrencyCode).ToList() //group the items by the currency code
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).First()).ToList(); //order by the id and get the first item.

    var values = result
        .Select(x => 
        $"{x.Id.ToString().PadLeft(3,' ')}" +
        $"{x.CurrencyCode.PadLeft(13,' ')}" +
        $"{x.BuyRate.ToString("N6").PadLeft(10,' ')}" +
        $"{x.SellRate.ToString("N6").PadLeft(10, ' ')}").ToList(); //return a list tabulated
```